# OpenGL drawPixels with fragment shader

Tags: opengl, pipeline, fragment-shader

I'm confused about the OpenGL pipeline. I have an openGL method where I am trying to use glDrawPixels with a fragment shader, so my code looks like:

```
// I setup the shader before this
glUseProgram(myshader);
glDrawPixels(...);
```

On some graphics cards the shader gets applied, but on others it does not. I've no problem with nvidia, but problems with various ATI cards. Is this a bug with the ATI card? Or is nvidia just more flexible and I'm misunderstanding the pipeline? Are there alternatives to working around this (other than texture mapping)?

thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 1):

glDrawPixels should have fragment shaders applied. Figure 3.1 of [page 203 of the compatibility profile](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec41.compatibility.20100725.pdf) makes it clear.

Note however, that the core profile removes DrawPixels. Which GL version are you using ?

Comment: @Bahbar, thanks for that diagram. It looks like the call to glDrawPixels works, just it isn't being shaded. I am using version 2.1 of openGL (it is a customer PC, so I cannot upgrade it).

Comment: So as the spec states it, it's again the guys from ATI not doing their work properly. What a surprise!

Comment: Well, that's yet another bug in ATI's drivers. So it's time to file bugs and chew bubble gum; and I'm all out of gum.

Comment: @Jeff: Are you sure the shader compiled and linked correctly ? it might be that you're using features not available in that version ? (or it might be hardware issues. 2.1 level GL cards at ATI were mostly R300 based, that did not have that many issues though).

Comment: @Bahbar, I did verify that the shader was compiling and linking properly. I was able to switch to using texture mapped quads and all worked well (with the same shader).

Comment: @datenwolf +1 from another definite John Carpenter fan!